# To sum up more than one array values in hash - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, sum, average

I have a hash example which has two element (section_one and section_two) in Ruby. I want to sum up each element separately and estimate each element average.

My hash:

```
class_grades = {
  :section_one => [88, 74, 64],
  :section_two => [99, 100]
}
```

I have tried on this code

```
sum = 0
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |value1|
    sum += value1
  end
    puts "#{key}: #{sum.to_f}"
end
```

but it turns out with the result:

```
section_one: 226.0
section_two: 425.0
```

I have a problem to sum up each element separately. It estimates firs element and goes on. Could you help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with minimum editing of your code:

```
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  sum = 0
  value.each do |value1|
    sum += value1
  end
    puts "#{key}: #{sum.to_f}"
end
```

But I'll recommend you do someth about:

```
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value.inject(:+).to_f}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and reliable answer!

Comment: @Syildiz You are welcome) 
You can mark one of these answers as right answer to help others to find solution to related questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set to zero `sum` at the beginning of your loop

```
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  sum = 0
  value.each do |value1|
    sum += value1
  end
  puts "#{key}: #{sum.to_f}"
end
```

There is a more idiomatic way to get the sum from an enumerable

```
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  sum = value.inject(0, :+)
  puts "#{key}: #{sum.to_f}"
end
```

And, you don't need that `.to_f`. `1 + 2.5` gets `3.5`

```
class_grades.each do |key, value|
  sum = value.inject(0, :+)
  puts "#{key}: #{sum}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and reliable answer!

Comment: What will be the result of `[88, 74, 64, 0.34].inject(:+)`? :)

Comment: Suggestion: use `inject(0,:+)` in cases where the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this:

```
class_grades.map { |k,v| [k, v.sum.fdiv(v.size).round(1)] }.to_h
 #=> { :section_one => 75.3, :section_two => 99.5 }
```

Key methods: `Array#sum` (>2.4.0), `Integer#fdiv` and `Float#round`. See [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org) for more info.

Comment: where does this sum come from? I get error when I run it.

Comment: This is a new method [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) introduced in Ruby 2.4.0

Comment: I am too newbie to find out that single line answer:) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Syildiz Yes this may be fairly complex if you're just starting out. I was just showing another way of doing things. Best of luck with studying Ruby.